# PDO fetch issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a very strong problem.

What I do?

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testing;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '', array (PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

$res = $pdo->query("SELECT `contents` AS `contents` FROM `sessions` WHERE `session_id` = '54d31554d74717-82758334' LIMIT 1")->fetchAll();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($res); echo "</pre>"; die;
```

Then I receive one of two answers:

[image: First answer]
[image: Second answer]

I receive first answer more often then second.

**Question**: Why I receive two different answers for one query?

Comment: Why FetchAll? Have you tried the first example of php manual for pdo query? -> http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Play with order by,when you get the second value is the session still in there?

Comment: Why are you aliasing a column to the same name? I suspect that may have something to do with the array key discrepancy.

Comment: @Marco Mura Yes, I tried.

Comment: @Mihai I have played with it. No changes.

Comment: @prodigitalson It is done by my framework. I just copied it's query.

Comment: I have restarted my MySQL server and problem disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PDO

`LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` will return indeterminate results,that is there is no guaranteed result.

Comment: Will it really give inconsistent column names?

Comment: @lonesomeday I didnt see the session in there,that is weird.Order by only explains the values

Comment: Small clarification - I check this code on different machines. Everywhere I have the first answer only/

Comment: @LastRide It doesnt matter if you have 2 results with LIMIT 1 wihtout ORDER BY you can get 1000 times the same result but 1001th time you get the other result.This is what indeterminate means.